# Почему Room меняет последовательность елементов при получении?

Tags: java, android

Вполне стандартная ситуация

Я сохраняю 4 елемента в БД в последовательности 1, 2, 3, 4

Я использую `Stetho` для того, чтоб посмотреть как они сохранились в БД и действительно все правильно сохранено

Но когда мне нужно получить все элементы с БД я использую такой метод

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :i AND state = :iS")
List<MyObj> getAll(String i,  String iS);
```

То порядок возвращенных элементов которые я получаю вот такой 1, 2, 4, 3

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL не гарантирует постоянный порядок строк, тем более в том порядке, в котором данные были размещены в БД
Стоит попробовать добавить сортировку вроде такого:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :i AND state = :iS ORDER BY id")
List<MyObj> getAll(String i,  String iS);
```

Только `id` заменить на то поле, которое хранит порядок добавления/следования элементов